# wildfly 10.0, jax-ws and stateful session

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wildfly-10

I want to build Jax-ws web service using Wildfly 10.0 and I want this web service with stateful session (read and write on session ),
I have searched for that, and I see the below link:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/stateful.htm#WSADV234

Unfortunately the session code did'n work
When I call sayHello method that use session, the time finished and returned (Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Message: java.lang.NullPointerException ).

I'm using Eclipse Mars, Dynamic web service, Wildfly 10.0, and the web service (server: using Wildfly 10.0, web service run-time: Apache Axis, and using ear file for this project)

The code is:

```
package com.sample;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://sample.com/", serviceName = "Test1Service", portName = "Test1Port")
@Stateful
public class Test1 {

@Resource
private WebServiceContext wsContext;

@WebMethod
public String sayHello() {
    MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext(); 
    HttpSession session = ((javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST))
            .getSession();

    if (session == null)
        throw new WebServiceException("No HTTP Session found");

    String item = "";
    try {
        item = (String) session.getAttribute("name1");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (item == null || item.equals(""))
        item = "good";

    session.setAttribute("name1", item);
    return "Hello " + session.getAttribute("name1");
}

@WebMethod
public int setValue(int x) {
    return x;
}
}
```

Please note the setValue method worked successfully, but the sayHello method did'nt work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody,

The problem: I was using Axis not Axis2 where Axis2 support Http session.